# div containers using display:flex only work properly in index.html

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Making a r/pcmasterrace website for a school project, tried using divs for the first real time, but having trouble making it work outside index.html . Internet ain't helping much.

**Situation**

I reference two stylesheets (with type="text/css") in each of my .html pages, but mainly use css/normalize.css as the stylesheet. The main index runs fine, with a left,middle, and right section. But on other .html pages, which make use of the same stylesheets, the containers are squished together. I have tried using all sorts of flexbox solutions, but none work for all the pages at once.

**Code**
First time using StackOverflow, sorry if it ain't great.

```css
html, 
body {/*css reset because i had wierd lines*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p{
    font-size:20px;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family:"Audiowide";/*very nice font*/
    font: size 200000;
}
.ignore-css{/* for stuff that needs to be cleaned*/
    all:unset; 
}
.colored {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red, orange , yellow,lightgreen, cyan, blue,blue,cyan,lightgreen,yellow,orange,red);
    border-radius:2px;
    border-top: 0;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-size: 200%;
    animation-name: colored;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: steps(512);
}
 
  @keyframes colored {
    from {background-position: 0% 0%;}  
      to {background-position: 200% 0%;}
}
.block1{
    border-top: 4px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-right: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
.block2{
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-right: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
.block3{
    border-top: 4px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-left: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
a{
    font-family:"Audiowide";
    float:top;
}
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: grey;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height:25px;
}   
  /* mouse over link */
 a:hover{
    color: white;
    border: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(255, 102, 0),rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    height:18px;
    font-size:110%;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}  
  /* selected link */
a:active.links,a:visited.links {
    color: cyan;
}

.maintext{
    color:grey;
    font-size: 48;
    text-size-adjust: 10;
}
.mainlist{
    color:grey;
    font-size: 40 !important;
    text-align:left;
    text-size-adjust: 10;
}
.mainimg{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 4;
}
.leftside,.rightside,.mainside{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 1200px;
}
.leftside{
    background-image:linear-gradient(-95deg,rgba(0,0,1,1),rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.379));
    text-align: center;
    width:25%;
    z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
    top: 0;/* Stay on top */
    padding-top: 2px;
    
}
.mainside{
    background-image:rgb(0,0,0);
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin: 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
    top: 0;/* Stay on top */
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.rightside{
    background-image:linear-gradient(95deg,rgba(0,0,1,1),rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.379));
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 75%;
    width:25%;
    z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
    top: 0;/* Stay on top */
    right: 0;/* Stay right */
    padding-top: 2px;
}

/*body at bottom because lowest piority*/
body{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PCMasterRace Fan Page</title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="leftside">
        <h1 class="maintext">Navagation</h1>
        <a href="whypc.html"  title="Why PC" target="_blank">Why PC?</a>
        <a href="guide.html"  title="EntryGuide" target="_blank">Guide</a>
        &nbsp
        <div class="links">
            <h1 class="maintext">Links</h1>
            <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Reddit" target="_blank">r/pcmasterrace</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/OfficialPCMR"  title="PC Master Race on Twitter" target="_blank">OfficialPCMR Twitter</a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/OfficialPCMasterRace"  title="PC Master Race on Facebook" target="_blank">OfficialPCMasterRace Facebook</a>
            <a href="https://discord.gg/pcmr"  title="PC Master Race on Discord" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Discord</a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pcmasterrace_official/"  title="PC Master Race on Instagram"target="_blank">PCMasterRace Instagram</a>
            <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/officialpcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Twitch" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Twitch Channel</a>
            <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steampcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Steam" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Steam Group</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqpfJtpeBIV_nr7FH2xrPow"  title="PC Master Race on YouTube" target="_blank">PCMasterRace YT Channel</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="mainside">
        <img class="mainimg" src="assets/rainbow-logo.gif" alt="rainbowlogo" style="float:center;">
        <hr class="colored">
        <div class="block1">
            <p class="maintext">
                Welcome to this fan-page of PCMasterRace. If you are a console peasant, please go <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage" class="ignore-css" style="height:4px;font: size 4px;">here</a> instead.
                We all know PCs have reached their golden age, where they are accessible to most people, but before cloud gaming services and Moore's law
                will ruin it all. r/PCMasterRace, set up by u/pedro19, is one of the largest subreddits and online communities, full with people following
                their love for PCs and all the goodness they bring. There are also variations of the online sub-culture, like r/linuxmasterrace,
                r/ultrawidemasterrace and others.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="block2">    
            <p class="maintext">
                The term "PCMasterRace" was first shown to the world by comedic writer Ben Croshaw in 2008. Although intially meant as a poke of fun towards
                the elitist attiude of the Witcher Community, it quickly spread, as do all internet quotes, to become an well-known expression of pride
                of what PCs have become. While it is technacilly a reference to Nazi-Germany's idea of a "master race", most users of the term do not 
                associate with that at all. This can be argued to be positive, as the previous use of the reference is no longer publicly used.
            </p>
        </div>
        <hr class="colored">
        <div class="block3" style="height:50px">
            &nsbp
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
        <h1 class="maintext">Current News</h1>
        <a href="news.html"  title="morenews" target="_blank">More News</a>
    </div>  

  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The style.css script only contains the following: body{background-color:black;}
As example, here is another page. This one gets squished, and I can't figure out why. The div classes are called leftside,mainside and rightside, and in normalize.css, are all both called induvially and together.

```css
html, 
body {/*css reset because i had wierd lines*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p{
    font-size:20px;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family:"Audiowide";/*very nice font*/
    font: size 200000;
}
.ignore-css{/* for stuff that needs to be cleaned*/
    all:unset; 
}
.colored {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red, orange , yellow,lightgreen, cyan, blue,blue,cyan,lightgreen,yellow,orange,red);
    border-radius:2px;
    border-top: 0;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-size: 200%;
    animation-name: colored;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: steps(512);
}
 
  @keyframes colored {
    from {background-position: 0% 0%;}  
      to {background-position: 200% 0%;}
}
.block1{
    border-top: 4px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-right: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
.block2{
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-right: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
.block3{
    border-top: 4px solid rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-left: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
a{
    font-family:"Audiowide";
    float:top;
}
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: grey;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height:25px;
}   
  /* mouse over link */
 a:hover{
    color: white;
    border: 4px solid;
    border-image-source:linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(255, 102, 0),rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    height:18px;
    font-size:110%;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}  
  /* selected link */
a:active.links,a:visited.links {
    color: cyan;
}

.maintext{
    color:grey;
    font-size: 48;
    text-size-adjust: 10;
}
.mainlist{
    color:grey;
    font-size: 40 !important;
    text-align:left;
    text-size-adjust: 10;
}
.mainimg{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(8,8,8,0.2),rgb(255, 102, 0));
    border-image-slice: 4;
}
.leftside,.rightside,.mainside{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 1200px;
}
.leftside{
    background-image:linear-gradient(-95deg,rgba(0,0,1,1),rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.379));
    text-align: center;
    width:25%;
    z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
    top: 0;/* Stay on top */
    padding-top: 2px;
    
}
.mainside{
    background-image:rgb(0,0,0);
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin: 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
    top: 0;/* Stay on top */
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.rightside{
    background-image:linear-gradient(95deg,rgba(0,0,1,1),rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.379));
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 75%;
    width:25%;
    z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
    top: 0;/* Stay on top */
    right: 0;/* Stay right */
    padding-top: 2px;
}

/*body at bottom because lowest piority*/
body{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Why PC?</title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <base href="index.html" target="_blank">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="leftside">
        <h1 class="maintext">Navagation</h1>
        <a href="index.html"  title="Home" target="_blank">Home</a>
        <a href="guide.html"  title="EntryGuide" target="_blank">Guide</a>
        &nbsp
        <div class="links">
            <h1 class="maintext">Links</h1>
            <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Reddit" target="_blank">r/pcmasterrace</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/OfficialPCMR"  title="PC Master Race on Twitter" target="_blank">OfficialPCMR Twitter</a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/OfficialPCMasterRace"  title="PC Master Race on Facebook" target="_blank">OfficialPCMasterRace Facebook</a>
            <a href="https://discord.gg/pcmr"  title="PC Master Race on Discord" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Discord</a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pcmasterrace_official/"  title="PC Master Race on Instagram"target="_blank">PCMasterRace Instagram</a>
            <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/officialpcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Twitch" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Twitch Channel</a>
            <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steampcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Steam" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Steam Group</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqpfJtpeBIV_nr7FH2xrPow"  title="PC Master Race on YouTube" target="_blank">PCMasterRace YT Channel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mainside">
        <img class="mainimg" src="assets/rainbow-logo.gif" alt="rainbowlogo" style="float:center;">
        <hr class="colored">
        <div class="block1">
            <p class="maintext">
               Especially if you are a console peasant, you may scuff at this subculture, without understanding its foundation. But it does have one,
               as there are many reasons why PCs are the superior physical platform to use.  
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="block2">    
            <ul class="mainlist">
                <li>Freedom of use</li>
                <li>Use cases</li>
                <li>Price to performance</li>
                <li>Compatibility</li>
                <li>Modularity</li>
                <li>Healthy market</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr class="colored">
        <div class="block3" style="height:50px">
            &nsbp
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
        <h1 class="maintext">Current News</h1>
        <a href="pages/news.html"  title="morenews" target="_blank">More News</a>
    </div>    

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Conclusion**
Not an experienced programmer, sorry, I know the code is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your "Why PC?" page doesn't fill the width of the screen is that you've forgotten to close a tag. In your `<div class="leftside">`, there's a `<div class="links">` that is not closed. Here is the fix:

```html
<div class="leftside">
    <h1 class="maintext">Navagation</h1>
    <a href="index.html"  title="Home" target="_blank">Home</a>
    <a href="guide.html"  title="EntryGuide" target="_blank">Guide</a>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="links">
        <h1 class="maintext">Links</h1>
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Reddit" target="_blank">r/pcmasterrace</a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/OfficialPCMR"  title="PC Master Race on Twitter" target="_blank">OfficialPCMR Twitter</a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/OfficialPCMasterRace"  title="PC Master Race on Facebook" target="_blank">OfficialPCMasterRace Facebook</a>
        <a href="https://discord.gg/pcmr"  title="PC Master Race on Discord" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Discord</a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pcmasterrace_official/"  title="PC Master Race on Instagram"target="_blank">PCMasterRace Instagram</a>
        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/officialpcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Twitch" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Twitch Channel</a>
        <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steampcmasterrace"  title="PC Master Race on Steam" target="_blank">PCMasterRace Steam Group</a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqpfJtpeBIV_nr7FH2xrPow"  title="PC Master Race on YouTube" target="_blank">PCMasterRace YT Channel</a>
    </div> <!-- HERE -->
</div>
```

Here is a version on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/IndependentSw/pen/KKwmKbd) that works.